# Variable is assigned but comes back "Name Error"

Tags: python, variables

```
result = adfuller(df["Milk, lbs/cow"])
def adf_check(time_series):

    result = adfuller(time_series)
    print("Augmented Dickey Fuller Test")
    labe = ['ADF Test Statistic', 'p-value', '# of lags', '# of Observations']

for value, label in zip (result, labe):
    print(label+ ' : ' + str(value))
```

I get this error tho the variable is clearly defined. Any reason this is not running?

```
NameError            
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-fa1014e81050> in <module>
      6     labe = ['ADF Test Statistic', 'p-value', '# of lags', '# of Observations']
      7 
----> 8 for value, label in zip (result, labe):
      9     print(label+ ' : ' + str(value))
     10 

NameError: name 'labe' is not defined
```

Comment: Different scope in the function which you don't even call. `return` the wanted value from the function and assign it to a variable when you call the function.

Comment: "I get this error tho the variable is clearly defined." Why do you think it is "clearly defined"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - the variable is clearly defined, just not in the right scope.

Comment: Well, yes, but that's still the first question I'd like to ask in applying the Socratic method :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = adfuller(df["Milk, lbs/cow"])
def adf_check(time_series):

    result = adfuller(time_series)
    print("Augmented Dickey Fuller Test")
    labe = ['ADF Test Statistic', 'p-value', '# of lags', '# of Observations']

    # indentation matters in python
    for value, label in zip (result, labe):
        print(label+ ' : ' + str(value))
```

Comment: Thanks everybody. I see what you mean - it's a scope problem.